Renormalisation Scheme (in)dependence of beta functions and observables
Suppose we have two schemes A and B. In scheme A, we set a four-point amplitude measured at energy $\mu$ to be $i\lambda_A$. In scheme B, we set the four-point amplitude to instead be $i(\lambda_B+\lambda_0)$, where $\lambda_0$ is some real number. (Here, subscripts of A and B denote the renormalised couplings in that scheme.)
It seems like the counterterm for scheme B is related to the counterterm for scheme A only by a simple renormalisation-scale-independent shift $\delta_B = \delta_A +\lambda_0$. This seems to suggest that the functional form of the $\beta$ functions as calculated using the Callan-Symanzik equation would be invariant under this scheme change. So, $\beta_{\lambda_A}(\lambda) = \beta_{\lambda_B}(\lambda)$.
However, it looks to me like this equality will lead to different predictions at another energy scale $\mu'$. In scheme A the four point function would have an amplitude $i\lambda_A(\mu')$ while in scheme B the four-point function would have amplitude $i(\lambda_B(\mu')+\lambda_0)$. But the relation $\lambda_A(\mu) = \lambda_B(\mu) +\lambda_0$ cannot possibly hold at all energy scales, if the beta functions are the same and nonconstant.
What's the mistake in my thought process?

If I recall correctly, only the leading term of the beta function of dimensionless parameters is universal. Otherwise, beta functions are scheme-dependent

Does this mean the leading order beta functions aren't predictive, since one could in principle cook up a renormalisation scheme to match observations with any renormalised coupling? Or do common physical schemes like the on-shell scheme somehow produce better approximations of the exact beta functions, than if one were to use some random unmotivated scheme?

Beta functions are not observables, so (apart from the leading coefficient) they can be anything in principle. Observables (such as on-shell quantities) will always be scheme-independent. I believe the numerical value of the normalized coupling can change, but the predictions of the theory will not

There is another way of understanding the renormalization scheme independence of the leading order beta function. You can derive is  from operator product expansion (OPE) coefficients. This is explained in Cardy’s book on renormalization.

I understand that beta functions are not observable and are scheme dependent. I am just trying to reconcile their scheme independence at leading order with the scheme independence of 4-point amplitudes. In the above example it looks like the amplitudes calculated in the different schemes $i\lambda_A(\mu)$ and $i(\lambda_B(\mu)+\lambda_0)$ can vary considerably over large enough energy scales.
